# Data safety in ArcGIS Server network

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, data, web-service

I want to know about the safety of data shared in an ArcGIS server network. Can someone hack into the network and steal the data? Suppose we create an ArcGIS web service and put up an application, can someone steal/hack the data in that web application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your question  :

1.Can someone hack into the network and steal the data? (According to me this is without ArcGIS Server i.e your spatial data including shape files ,raster data etc.)

Ans: No. If you secure data then its not possible to hack data (I assume that  your IT admin has assigned user-name and password + permissions to everyone.)

Please read more in the [web help of arcgis server 10.1](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01540000039r000000) + Go though my previous [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43589/data-security-for-gis-data-esri-shape-files-auto-cad-files) regarding this...

2.Suppose we create an ArcGIS web service and put up an application, can someone steal/hack the data in that web application?

Ans :No its not possible. Please read more regarding [Configuring ArcGIS Server security](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000005qz000000).

Let us know if you have any questions..

thanks..

Comment: I'll just add that the important thing is to secure everything down. If you have enabled anonymous access to your REST Endpoint & SOAP Endpoint, it is very easy to extract data from your services. If you leave things at the default settings, there is no security.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe Good Point