# Is it possible to withhold attribute data from a shapefile?

Tags: shapefile, attribute-table, security

Basically, what I'm trying to figure out is if its possible to withhold or lock attribute data from a shapefile if you are sending the shapefile to someone?

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/43589

Answer (score 2):

Right click whichever field/s you want to withhold, select 'Turn Field Off', export as you normally would, the field/s will not be in the export.

Comment: To be clear on Maksim's suggestion...you must export it to a new file...just turning a field off, zipping and emailing it will do nothing.

Comment: That works for 'withholding' i.e. not giving those attributes. If you want to ensure that they don't change anything either make the .dbf (and .shp) file *read only* in explorer or supply on a CD using snail mail. This will guarantee that they will not be able to edit/modify the shapefile (unless they change the attributes). If you're using Esri there is a SDX format that is compressed and read only or a file geodatabase that has been compressed is uneditable. One would ask why? what are you trying to avoid? If we knew more about what you're trying to achieve we could be more specific.

Comment: There's also a (in my opinion) more convenient interface for turning fields on and off if you have to do a number of them. On the layer's Properties dialog, there is a Fields tab with a list and checkboxes.

Comment: I would be cautious with the suggestions here.  None of these will prevent data that is sent to someone in shapefile format from being viewed/modified.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute data in a Shapefile is stored in a dBase III file (.dbf) which is a file format that's over thirty years old.  This format has no native support for encryption or security, so if you send someone a Shapefile there is no way to prevent them from accessing or changing the data.